# Format xml output in spring boot

Tags: xml, spring-boot, jaxb, jersey

I have a simple endpoint as follows:

```
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public Foo[] getFoo() {
    List<Foo> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Foo("bar"));
    list.add(new Foo("baz"));
    list.add(new Foo("bat"));
    return list.toArray(new Foo[list.size()]);
}
```

When I send a request to this endpoint using curl as follows:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/xml" localhost:8080/foo
```

The output is like this:

```
<Foos>
 <item>
   <name>bar</name>
 </item>
 <item>
   <name>baz</name>
 </item>
 <item>
   <name>bat</name>
</item>
</Foos>
```

Is there a way to instruct spring boot to change item to name of class Foo?

Here is the Foo class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo {

private String name;

public Foo() {
}

public Foo(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Jersey for the same endpoint and class outputs the desired format (Foo instead of item). How can I achieve this in spring mvn without changing the Foo class?

Here is the desired xml output:

```
<Foos>
<Foo>
  <name>bar</name>
</Foo>
<Foo>
  <name>baz</name>
</Foo>
<Foo>
  <name>bat</name>
</Foo>
```

So basically I would like to be able to have control over the name of the elements without modifying the Foo class.

Comment: Can you add the desired output you want in `xml` it would be easier to understand what are you aiming to achieve. Thanks.

Comment: @lazarov see the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
 @XmlRootElement(name="Foos")
    public class GetFooResponse{


        private List<Foo> someList;


        @XmlElement(name="Foo")
        public List<Foo> getSomeList() {
            return someList;
        }

        public void setSomeList(List<Foo> someList) {
            this.someList = someList;
        } 

        public GetResponse(List<Foo> someListValue) {
            this();
            this.someList = someListValue;  
        }

        /**
         * 
         */
        public GetResponse() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
    }
```

This will maybe generate the output you want. You have to replace the return type of your method from `Foo[]` -> `GetFooResponse`.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately I cannot go with the wrapper solution. Because this affect the json output which is not desirable.

Comment: Can you add extra annotations to the Foo.class at least or it is auto generated from some *.wsdl file and you are not allowed to modify it in any way ?

Comment: The reason I cannot change Foo class is that it is used by other services implemented in Jax rs. I am implementing a similar service in spring boot so want to have exact output without changing domain objects in anyway.

Comment: Let me see if I get this straight : 

You **can't use wrapper** and you **can't modify the the Foo.class** in any way.

So the solution should be ugly then. Did you consider using `Nodes` ?

Comment: That is true. And what is Nodes?

Comment: Taka a look at this methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17078308/how-to-marshal-a-jaxb-object-to-org-w3c-dom-document) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531129/how-to-rename-xml-node-name) . The one is how to rename your nodes and the other is how to end up with a `Document` from `Object` .